# How to display only certain items in the ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListView in which some elements are shown

```
<ListView x:Name="ListaTestiCanzone" ItemClick="TestiCanzone_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Testo}}" SelectionChanged="TestiCanzone_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,-10,-0.167,9.667">

 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Width="300">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NomeCanzone}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NomeArtista}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Anno}"/>

 </StackPanel>
```

I created some Checkbox in a HUBSection in which I would like to see only certain items in the ListView, and not all of them.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Uomo" Content="Uomo" IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
```

How would I go then to display only the items in the ListView with the property "Sesso = "Uomo"?

```
List<Testo> song = new List<Testo>
        {

            new Testo
            {                    
                Anno=2012,
                NomeCanzone="Estate",
                NomeArtista="Jovanotti",
                Sesso="Uomo",
                PercorsoFile= @"/Assets/Testi/Estate.txt" 

            },

            new Testo
            {
                Anno=2012,
                NomeCanzone="Terra degli uomini",
                NomeArtista="Jovanotti",
                Sesso="Uomo",
                PercorsoFile="",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding to the collection directly, go through a `CollectionView` object. Then set the `Filter` property to a predicate that evaluates using your check box and condition, as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter(v=vs.110).aspx).

The function would be something like:

```
private void ShowUomoFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Testo item = (Testo)e.Item;
        if (item.Sesso == "Uomo")
           e.Accepted = true;
        else
           e.Accepted = false;
    }
    else
       e.Accepted = true;
}
```

Since the filter is all view-related, setting this up through the code-behind is OK.